# What tools do you use to solve these puzzles?

Tags: knowledge

So, I know that this is more a puzzle-question-gets-asked sort of gig. But I was wondering what tools you all use to solve these puzzles. I know that creativity and logic are a must, but when it comes to codes and ciphers and things that require computing, what tools do you use? Websites? Programs you've made?

Comment: Brains and python programs.

Comment: @riskymysteries  I suppose I should have added that I would like to know where to access these tools... I am an inexperienced newbie and need to know how to get started

Comment: Find all anagrams with https://www.thewordfinder.com/anagram-solver/

Comment: Find all rhymes with https://www.rhymezone.com/

Comment: I think what you're looking for is this post over on Meta: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/a-collection-of-puzzling-tools

Comment: I usually use Hill Climbing implemented in Java.